# Multi step form

Tags: 7, forms

How can I create multi step form in Drupal 7?

```
function module_template_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items['them-noi-dung'] = array(
        'title' => t('Khai báo hóa chất'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('module_template_select_form',2),
        'access callback' => true,
    );
    return $items;
    }
function module_template_select_form($form, &$form_state){
    $form = array();
    $form['select'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' =>'Lựa chọn hình thức khai báo',
        '#options' => array('0'=>t('Khai báo lần đầu'), '1'=>t('Đã từng khai báo')),
        '#default_value' => '0', 
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Tiếp tục'),
    );
    return $form;
    }
function module_template_ma_so_thue_form($form, &$form_state){
    $form = array();
    $form['masothue'] = array(
        '#type' => 'text',
        '#title' =>'Nhập vào mã số thuế',
        );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Tiếp tục'),
    );
    return $form;
    }
function module_template_select_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $select = $form_state['values']['select'];
    if($select==0){
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/khai-bao-hoa-chat';
        }elseif($select==1){
            $form_state['storage']['step']='module_template_ma_so_thue_form';
            }
```

I want when select `$form['select']` with `value = 1` then submit go to `module_template_ma_so_thue_form`

Comment: you can find here http://davidsonj.com/blog/how-create-multi-step-form-drupal-7

Comment: another related to this http://www.grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7